# Show convexity of a set using the definition of convex set

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Show, using the definition of convex set, that the set $S=\{(x_1,x_2) | 3x_1-5x_2\geq 15\}$ is convex.

I have started the proof by letting $y=(y_1,y_2),$ $z=(z_1,z_2) \in S$ and letting $t \in (0,1)$. I know we want to show that $ty+(1-t)z \in S$. I have plugged in $y,z$ in the equation, but am not sure how this shows that the set is convex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $y,z\in S$.  Then $3y_1-5y_2\geq 15$ and $3z_1-5z_2\geq 15$.  Let $t\in(0,1)$ and consider $ty+(1-t)z$.  Note that I didn't write $ty+(1-t)z\in S$ as in the question, because the $\in S$ part is what must be shown.

Observe that $ty+(1-t)z=(ty_1+(1-t)z_1,ty_2+(1-t)z_2)$.  Consider 
$$
3(ty_1+(1-t)z_1)-5(ty_2+(1-t)z_2)=t(3y_1-5y_2)+(1-t)(3z_1-5z_2).
$$
Since $3y_1-5y_2\geq 15$ and $3z_1-5z_2\geq 15$, we can substitute these inequalities into above to get that 
$$
t(3y_1-5y_2)+(1-t)(3z_1-5z_2)\geq 15t+(1-t)15=15.
$$
Therefore $ty+(1-t)z\in S$.